# Function - encrypt key

Tags: python, function, encryption

I'm trying to create a function that encrypts a number of 4 digits insert by the user.

I was able to reach this:

```
while True:
    num = int(input('Insira um valor entre 1000 e 9999: '))
    if num<1000 or num>9999:
        print('Insira um valor válido.')
    else:
        break

num_str = str(num)

def encrypt(num):
    num_encrip = ''
    for i in num_str:
        match i:
            case '1':
                num_encrip = 'a'
            case '2': 
                num_encrip = '*'
            case '3':
                num_encrip = 'I'
            case '4':
                num_encrip = 'D'
            case '5':
                num_encrip = '+'
            case '6':
                num_encrip = 'h'
            case '7':
                num_encrip = '@'
            case '8':
                num_encrip = 'c'
            case '9':
                num_encrip = 'Y'
            case '0':
                num_encrip = 'm'
        print(num_encrip, end='')
```

encrypt(num_str)

And it works fine, but I know this isn't very efficient and using lists should be better. And here I'm stuck because I can't adapt the code above with lists...

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
chars = ['a', '*', 'I', 'D', '+', 'h', '@' 'c', 'Y', 'm']

while True:
    num = int(input('Insira um valor entre 1000 e 9999: '))
    if num<1000 or num>9999:
        print('Insira um valor válido')
    else:
        break

num_str = str(num)

def encrypt():
    pass

encrypt(num_str)
```

I'd writted so much thing inside the function encrip, but nothing works... I'm stuck... any help, please? I know I have to do a for loop... but what exactly?

Thank you.

Comment: you should use dictionary, not a list with `num` being a key (i.e. `{'6': 'h'}`. BTW: it's spelled "encrypt".

Comment: There isn't really any encryption mechanism in this code since it just statically maps numbers to characters. It would be trivial for an attacker to "decrypt" the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the 2 list, I'd suggest making a mapping from the numbers to the chars

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
chars = ['a', '*', 'I', 'D', '+', 'h', '@', 'c', 'Y', 'm']
correspondances = dict(zip(nums, chars))

def encrip2(value):
    num_encrip = ''
    for c in value:
        num_encrip += correspondances[int(c)]
    print(num_encrip)
```

And as the indexes are ints, you can directly use them as indexes into the chars

```
chars = 'ma*ID+h@cY'
def encrip2(value):
    num_encrip = ''
    for c in value:
        num_encrip += chars[int(c)]
    print(num_encrip)
```

Comment: Wow, that works. I haven't studied the zip function yet... In fact, I didn't even know it existed. One more thing to learn.
Thank you!!